# Define custom function on-the-fly in dplyr::mutate_at() function

Tags: r, dplyr

I was to use `dplyr::mutate_at()` to change values of certain columns in a `data.frame` using some custom defined function. Below are my code :

```
library(dplyr)
data(iris)
iris %>% mutate_at('Sepal.Length', ~ function(x1 = ., x2 = 100) return(x1 + x2))
```

With this I am getting below error :

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `Sepal.Length`.
ℹ `Sepal.Length = (structure(function (..., .x = ..1, .y = ..2, . = ..1) ...`.
✖ `Sepal.Length` must be a vector, not a function.
```

I want to define my custom function just within the `dplyr::mutate_at()` only.

Could you please help me to understand why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `~` when you use the `function()` keyword:

`iris %>% mutate_at('Sepal.Length', function(x1 = ., x2 = 100) return(x1 + x2))`

```
> iris %>% mutate_at('Sepal.Length', function(x1 = ., x2 = 100) return(x1 + x2))
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1          105.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
2          104.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
3          104.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
4          104.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa
```

Comment: ahh. I was overthinking..